# Centos openmp with gcc 4.1.2

Tags: linux, centos, openmp

I cant tell if openmp is installed in this fresh install of centos I just put on with the developer tools.

I tried to run ldconfig -p | grep openmp and I dont see it listed.

Is it available for centos with that version of gcc?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep gomp
```

library is call `libgomp`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep -i "gomp"
libgomp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1
```

Basically, it's called `gomp`... GCC's OpenMP.

The alternative is to compile a hello world openmp program; if it doesn't work, it isn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

Search "yum search gomp" this way on a Red Hat distro. To find out what the groups are use "yum grouplist | less". This pages the output so you can see the complete list. You will notice which groups are installed and available. Of course you can always use "yum help".

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with CentOS or `yum`, but take a stab with this:

```
yum list installed | grep "penmp"
```

Good luck!